# Select record from 3 tables using inner and outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I want to select records `product_id    product_name    actual_price    discount_price` from `oc_product, oc_product_description, oc_product_special`. `oc_product_special` table contains discount price of product but on some products there is no discount i.e. discount_price=0.0000. I want to select all 40 products with their discount_price and if discount_price=0.0000 then print NULL in that row.

Query which I tried is:

```
SELECT oc_product_description.product_id,oc_product_description.name product_name, oc_product.price actual_price, oc_product_special.price discount_price 
FROM oc_product 
INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN oc_product_special ON oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product.product_id = oc_product_special.product_id`
```

it returns me wrong output like

```
product_id  product_name    actual_price    discount_price
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            0.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            1950.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            3850.0000
  NULL            NULL             NULL            7500.0000
```

And I expect this output:

```
product_id  product_name    actual_price    discount_price
  1               yyyy             1000.0000      0.0000
  2               xxxx             2000.0000      500.0000
```

Comment: Provide sample data set for your tables

Comment: Show the ddl please.

Comment: You're talking about 0.000 you want NULL in that row, but your desired result shows 0.000. Is that a typo, or am I mis-reading the question?

Comment: Note that the use of RIGHT JOIN is vanishingly rare. For every RIGHT JOIN there is (theoretically) a functionally identical LEFT JOIN, and one which most people (me included) would find more intuitive. I say 'theoretically' just because very occasionally, on more complex queries, it can be hard to work out what the equivalent LEFT JOIN is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things;

Your join condition between `oc_product` and `oc_product_description` should be on the inner join between them, not in the outer join with the third table;

```
INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
  ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id
```

The condition on your outer join should in this case only contain the condition on that table;

```
RIGHT OUTER JOIN oc_product_special 
  ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_special.product_id
```

Also, since you probably always want the description of the item to always be there, and the special price to be optional, you should probably use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `RIGHT JOIN`;

That would result in a final query similar to;

```
SELECT oc_product_description.product_id,oc_product_description.name product_name, 
       oc_product.price actual_price, oc_product_special.price discount_price 
FROM oc_product 
INNER JOIN oc_product_description 
  ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN oc_product_special 
  ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_special.product_id
```

Comment: As a side note, `oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product.product_id = oc_product_special.product_id` does not check that all 3 values are the same, for that you'd need something like `oc_product_description.product_id = oc_product.product_id AND  oc_product_special.product_id = oc_product_description.product_id`